# How to remove the color around this icon on BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, android-studio

[I want to remove the color around this icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXQL3.png)

I tried to learn a lot through videos but failed. I want you to help me I tried to learn a lot through videos but failed. I want you to help me I have been researching for many days and to no avail

Comment: Please edit your question by sending the code

Comment: please send the code for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom style in your res/values/styles.xml file:

```
<style name="BottomNavigationViewStyle" 
    parent="Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView">
    <item name="android:background">null</item>
</style>
```

Apply the custom style to your BottomNavigationView in the layout XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
    style="@style/BottomNavigationViewStyle"/>
```